# psycopg2: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extras'

Tags: python, psycopg2, importerror

In my code I use the [`DictCursor`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor) from `psycopg2.extras` like this

```
dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
```

However, all of the sudden I get the following error when I load the cursor:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extras'
```

Maybe something is dorked in my installation but I have no clue where to start looking. I made some updates with pip, but as far as I know no dependencies of `psycopg2`.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You need to explicitly import `psycopg2.extras`:

```
import psycopg2.extras
```

Comment: As of July 2020, the import psycopg2.extras works for me

Comment: Note: need `import psycopg2` and `import psycopg2.extras` and use as `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`, no `extras.DictCursor`

Comment: @e-info128 In order to use `psycopg2.extras.DictCursor`, only `import psycopg2.extras` is needed. The `import psycopg2` isn't strictly needed, though, I personally always include it because it makes the dependency for `psycopg2.connect` obvious.

Answer (score 7):

As of July 2018, the `import psycopg2.extras` doesn't work for me.
The following works for me:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

and later:

```
>>> import psycopg2.errorcodes
>>> psycopg2.errorcodes.UNIQUE_VIOLATION
'23505'
```